# Changing global variable in event is not working right

Tags: javascript, dom-events, phantomjs

I have code in plain js where the event handler changes a global variable without passing it in.

```
"use strict";
var outsideEventString ="hello";
console.log("before event " + outsideEventString);

const EventEmitter = require('events');

class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {}

const myEmitter = new MyEmitter();

/*
  Assume a and b are outside your control, 
  but you still need to set the outsideEventString arg
*/
myEmitter.on('event', function(a, b) {
  console.log(a, b, this);
  console.log("inside event " + outsideEventString);
  outsideEventString="goodbye";
});
myEmitter.emit('event', 'a', 'b');

// this prints out goodbye which is set in the handler only
console.log("after event " + outsideEventString);
```

After adding the `onDOMContentLoaded` event and handler to the phantomjs example netlog.js, the code looks like:

```
"use strict";
console.log("netlog.js");
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    address;

var valueString = "hello";
var value1 = {
    current: false,
    timeStamp: null
};
if (system.args.length === 1) {
    //console.log('Usage: phantomjs netlog.js <some URL>');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    var PHANTOM_FUNCTION_PREFIX = '/* PHANTOM_FUNCTION */';
    address = system.args[1];
    page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
        if (msg.indexOf(PHANTOM_FUNCTION_PREFIX) === 0) {
            eval('(' + msg + ')()');
        } else {
            console.log(msg);
        }
    };
    page.onInitialized = function() {
        // add handler & apply value1 to handler's scope'
        page.evaluate(function(domContentLoaded) {
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', domContentLoaded, false);
        }, page.onDOMContentLoaded.apply(this, value1));
    };
    // handler has access to value1 and valueString
    page.onDOMContentLoaded = function(event) {
            value1.current = true;
            value1.timeStamp = Date.now();
            valueString="goodbye";
            console.log('**** DOM CONTENT LOADED ****');
    };
    page.onResourceReceived = function (res) {
        console.log('received ' + res.id + ' ' + res.stage);
    };
    page.onError = function (msg, trace) {
        console.log(msg);
        trace.forEach(function(item) {
            //console.log('  ', item.file, ':', item.line);
        });
    };
    page.open(address, function (status) {
        console.log("page opened");
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('FAIL to load the address');
        }
        console.log("value = " + JSON.stringify(value1));
        console.log("valueString=" + valueString);
        phantom.exit();
    });
}
```

With the code, as is, the valueString is 'goodbye' even though it isn't passed in via the `.apply(this,value1)`.

The output shows:

```
netlog.js
received 1 start
received 1 end
received 2 end
received 3 start
received 3 end
**** DOM CONTENT LOADED ****
received 5 start
received 5 end
received 6 start
received 6 end
received 7 start
received 9 start
received 8 start
received 7 end
received 9 end
received 8 end
received 4 start
received 4 end
page opened
value = {"current":true,"timeStamp":1473693805039}
valueString=goodbye
**** DOM CONTENT LOADED ****
**** DOM CONTENT LOADED ****
```

The `valueString` variable is set at the right url received id of 3 and it sticks so that I can see it inside the `page.open`.

Why does '**** DOM CONTENT LOADED ****' print after the page.open?

But if I change the `page.onInitialized` to the following, without the apply, neither `value1` or `valueString` is set.

```
page.onInitialized = function() {
    // add handler & apply value1 to handler's scope'
    page.evaluate(function(domContentLoaded) {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', domContentLoaded, false);
    }, page.onDOMContentLoaded);
};
```

Why do I need to use the apply method at all to get the global variables to be set inside the handler?

Why do I only have to pass in `value1` to the apply to be able to set `valueString`?

Comment: Events are processed asynchronously.

Comment: Hi Barmar, yes, that is correct, how does that explain the differences between straight js and phantomjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`page.evaluate` is the door to the page context in PhantomJS. Only primitive objects can be passed in. From the [docs](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html):

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the `evaluate` function must
>   be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be
>   serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> **Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will *not* work!**

So, `page.onDOMContentLoaded` is a function and cannot be passed into the page context. You have to pass and object into the page context and define a function there.

You can use something like this instead (using [the `onCallback` & `callPhantom` pair](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-callback.html)):

```
page.onCallback = function(data){
    if (data.type == 'DOMContentLoaded') {
        console.log('outer: DOMContentLoaded');
    }
};
page.onInitialized = function() {
    page.evaluate(function(value1) {
        // TODO: do something with value1
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
            console.log('inner: DOMContentLoaded');
            window.callPhantom({ type: 'DOMContentLoaded' });
        }, false);
    }, value1);
};
```

---

> Why does '**** DOM CONTENT LOADED ****' print after the page.open?

Remember that `Function.prototype.apply` immediately executes a function. In this case, it's the `page.onDOMContentLoaded` function inside of `page.onInitialized`. So whenever the page is "initialized" you will see the result of the execution of `page.onDOMContentLoaded`.

Why two pages are initialized after the execution stopped is a completely different question. This is probably only some peculiarity of PhantomJS.

Comment: Thank you Artjom for the explanation. I edited my question to include final working code and output.

Comment: No problem, but please don't include "the solution" in the question body (I've reverted it). That would only confuse future readers. You can post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Base on Artjom B. Answer, here is the working code:

```
"use strict";
console.log("netlog.js");
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    address;

var valueString = "hello";
var value1 = {
    current: false,
    timeStamp: null
};
if (system.args.length === 1) {
    //console.log('Usage: phantomjs netlog.js <some URL>');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    var PHANTOM_FUNCTION_PREFIX = '/* PHANTOM_FUNCTION */';
    address = system.args[1];
    page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
        if (msg.indexOf(PHANTOM_FUNCTION_PREFIX) === 0) {
            eval('(' + msg + ')()');
        } else {
            console.log(msg);
        }
    };
    page.onCallback = function(data){
        if (data.type == 'DOMContentLoaded') {
            value1.current = true;
            value1.timeStamp = Date.now();
            valueString = "goodbye";
            console.log('outer: DOMContentLoaded');
        }
    };
    page.onInitialized = function() {
        page.evaluate(function() {
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
                console.log('inner: DOMContentLoaded');
                window.callPhantom({ type: 'DOMContentLoaded' });
            }, false);
        });
    };
    page.onResourceReceived = function (res) {
        console.log('received ' + res.id + ' ' + res.stage);
    };
    page.onError = function (msg, trace) {
        console.log(msg);
        trace.forEach(function(item) {
            //console.log('  ', item.file, ':', item.line);
        });
    };
    page.open(address, function (status) {
        console.log("page opened");
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('FAIL to load the address');
        }
        console.log("value = " + JSON.stringify(value1));
        console.log("valueString=" + valueString);
        phantom.exit();
    });
}
```

This code allows the onDOMContentLoaded event handler to set the timestamp for the event - which is a global variable.